# Human readable URL causes a problem in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I have a basic CRUD with "Company" model. To make the company name show up, I did

```
def to_param
  name.parameterize
end
```

Then I accessed `http://localhost:3000/companies/american-express` which runs `show` action in the companies controller.

Obviously this doesn't work because the `show` method is as following:

```
def show
  @company = Company.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

The `params[:id]` is `american-express`. This string is not stored anywhere.

Do I need to store the short string (i.e., "american-express") in the database when I save the record? Or is there any way to retrieve the company data without saving the string in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send the ID with the parameterized value;

```
def to_param
    new_record? ? super : "#{id}-#{name}"
end
```

And when you collect the data in the show method, you can use the whole parameter;

```
def show
    @company = Company.find("12-american-express"); // equals to find(12)
end
```

There's also a plugin called permalink_fu, which you can read more about [here](http://www.seoonrails.com/even-better-looking-urls-with-permalink_fu.html).

Comment: Interesting solution. Leaving the "id" at the beginning of the param is interesting. I just ran `"12-american-express".to_i` and it returned `12`.

Answer (score 2):

I think [friendly_id](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) is more usable.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar with the `Category` model in my blog software. If you can guarantee that the only conversion the `parameterize` method is doing to your company names is replacing space characters with dashes then you can simply do the inverse:

```
def show
  @company = Company.find_by_name(params[:id].gsub(/-/, ' '))
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, "parameterize" is much more complicated. It does does more than changing the space and case.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I didn't know what constraints you have on your company names.

Answer (score 0):

Try permalink_fu plugin, which creates SEO friendly URLs in rails

http://github.com/technoweenie/permalink_fu

cheers

sameera

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [friendly_id](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem also.
It gives you the flexibility to use persited permalink slugs, also strip diacritics, convert to full ASCII etc.
Basically it makes your life a lot easier, and you get "true" permalinks (no to_param and the id workaround needed) with little effort.

Oh and did i mention that the permalinks are also versioned, so you can make old outdated permalinks to redirect to the current one? :)